# データフレームのqueryに渡す引数を変数で設定する方法について

Tags: python3, pandas

python の queryに渡す引数に、変数を指定する方法

この
https://nekoyukimmm.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/06/21/100821
辺りを見ながら作業しています。

こういう感じの定義、
lst_colm = dfSample.colums

for key in lst_colm:
dfSample = dfSample.query('@key == "新宿"', engine='python')

というように、queryを実行しようとすると、

args:<attribute 'args' of 'BaseException' objects>
<class 'KeyError'>
というエラーが出ます。

今回のデータフレームの列名は、
lst_colm = ['C:\日本\北海道', 'C:\日本\東北', 'C:\日本\関東', ・・・ ]
という風に、全角やその他記号（:, \ ）がいろいろ混ざった文字列なのですが、この辺の扱ううえで何か対策をしないといけないのでしょうか？

【補足】普通に表示するだけ、例えば
print(dfSample[lst_colm [0]])
という使い方はできるようなので、記号（:, \ ）が入っていることが悪さしているとも思えないのですが、、、

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何を行うのか今ひとつ分かりません。`lst_colm` の中から"新宿"を見つける？…('C:\日本\北海道' などしか) 入っていないのでは？ また, `@val` で値は指定できてもカラム名は指定できなかったと記事にも書いてあります。それにカラム名が仮に `1+1` だとしたら `df.query('1+1 == "新宿"')` … これで queryできるとは思えませんが (無効な文字を含むカラム名)

Comment: 質問のコードは「AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'colums'」のエラーが出るようです。実際に実行されたコードを掲載いただけませんか？ また、欲しい結果が何なのか示していただけませんか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ここに載せたコードは、説明用に作ったのもので実際のコードは違います。実際のコードはネットには載せられないので、この質問はここで終わりにします。　お騒がせしてすみませんでした。